# MSTEST test results don't show up using Test Explorer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

**Environment is:**

[image: Visual Studio 2013]

**Debugging a working Unit Test**

[image]

Test runs fine, as I see this at bottom of Test Explorer:

[image: TestResults]

If I click on output above, I see this:

[image: StandardOutput]

The output above created from Trace.WriteLine statement:

[image: TraceWriteLine]

If I go to the Solution Folder named Test Results I see this:

[image]

But Nothing is in there.

**Question:**

How do I get a copy of the test results as shown in the output window above?

**What hasn't Worked**

I created a solution .runsettings file, speicifying just the folder name, nothing showed up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test results (exported to a different directory, usually with a deploy attribute) are deleted when test succeeds. Make it fail, or explore the output while a breakpoint is hit

Comment: I need to stop the deletion so we can send these results as reports after a test run to other people.

Comment: Try to export to another directory. Which you cleanup in an assemblycleanup method